How to get unique results on a query in elasticsearch?
I have been trying to get unique results on a query in elasticsearch. The query that I have written is given below. I am trying to get a solution to get unique results on the field called "penny". Thanks in advance.
    {
  "query": {
      "exists": {
        "field": "penny"
      }
    }
  }
}


What exactly you mean by unique results? To get list of all values that exists for field penny?

Penny can have duplicate records and the results are huge. For example, the filter will result @MilanGatyás
400012121312
400012121312
400012121396
400012121334
400012121334
I want it to return only the following (only unique penny records):
400012121312
400012121396
400012121334

you can find it here:
Return Unique Values

@AbhinavArya based on your comment I think you might benefit from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html

Try the terms aggregation
Your documents
PUT /unique_results/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"penny":400012121312}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"penny":400012121312}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"penny":400012121396}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"penny":400012121334}
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"penny":400012121334}

Query
GET /unique_results/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "aggs": {
        "by_penny": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "penny",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_penny" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : 400012121312,
                    "doc_count" : 2
                },
                {
                    "key" : 400012121334,
                    "doc_count" : 2
                },
                {
                    "key" : 400012121396,
                    "doc_count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

